# App Delegate, after OAuth, can't close the WebView

Tags: swift, webview, oauth, appdelegate

I have this in my Appdelegate.swift

```
        case .reddit:
        if (url.host == "oauth-callback") {
            AuthorizationManager.removeRedditToken()
            print("Oauth Request..")
            let urlc = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
            let bearerToken = urlc?.queryItems?.first(where: { $0.name == "code" })?.value
            let tokenPromise = TokenManager.sharedInstance.fetchAccesTokenPromise(withBearerToken: bearerToken ?? "")
            tokenPromise.done { (token) in
                TokenManager.sharedInstance.accessToken = token.accessToken
                TokenManager.sharedInstance.refrestToken = token.refreshToken
                print("Access Token")
                print(token.accessToken)
                print("_______")
                print(token.refreshToken)
                AuthorizationManager.saveRedditToken(token: token.accessToken)
                AuthorizationManager.saveRedditRefreshToken(token: token.refreshToken!)
            }.catch { (error) in
                print(error)
            }
```

And I want to close the web view that opens during the open url function, but I can't figure out how to do it. The only way the Web View dismisses is by pressing "Done". It should close when I receive successfully the token. Dunno what can I do

Comment: How and where is the web view presented in the app?

Comment: In a safari view controller, when a button is pressed.